# jQuery Auto Injector Addon/Extension for Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I use a jQuery injector for chrome. This allows me to when I visit any website with the predefined script, it automatically injects. How ever, though I only have found a few and to my recolection, two that are reliable, I can't seem to find any for firefox. I will link the extensions of reference to what I use or have used. Additionally I am stating not just to inject but automatically inject even if you restart the browser. If it is possible to use a firefox extension to allow chrome extensions, please also inform me, thanks!

I currently use: [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/script-injector/gidddlfmjhjiibffpalikbecknoflfab)

I don't use: [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jscript-tricks/odialddippdmebbfbflcneemfdglimod)

**UPDATE: Workaround:** My [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/computerguy/T2F4w/) and [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/greasemonkey/)

The Jquery Code:

```
/*
$('.guide').hide(0);
$('#appbar-guide-menu').hide(0);
$('#watch-discussion').hide(0).delay(0).show(0);
$('#guide-container').hide(0).delay(0).show(0);
$('#guide-main').hide(0).delay(0).show(0);
$('#watch7-sidebar').hide(0).delay(0).show(0);
*/




/**** (Add To) tab switch ****/

$(document).ready(function(){
count = 0; limit = 10;
var refreshId = setInterval( function() {
if(count < limit) {

$( '.feed-load-more-container .text' ).delay(1500).click();count++;
$( '.playlist-add-video-url-button-add' ).delay(1500).click();count++;
$( '.yt-uix-button-content:contains("Add to")' ).delay(1500).click();count++;
$( '.playlist-title:contains("2014")' ).delay(2500).css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#fff", "font-weight":"bold"} );count++;
$( '.playlist-title:contains("2013")' ).delay(2500).css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#aaa", "font-weight":"bold"} );count++;

}
else {
clearInterval(refreshId);
}
}, 15000);
});






/****hide any user videos****/

$(document).ready(function()
{
var refreshId = setInterval( function() 
{

$( '.yt-shelf-grid-item:contains("Minecraft") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );

}, 10000);

jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
});







/*hide any videos on main feed containing*/

$(document).ready(function()
{
var refreshId = setInterval( function() 
{

$( '.result-list .result-item-padding:contains("year ago") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.result-list .result-item-padding:contains("years ago") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.result-list .result-item-padding:contains("month ago") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.result-list .result-item-padding:contains("months ago") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );

$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Notebook") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );

$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Rage Quit") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Lets Play") ') .css( {"opacity":"1" , "text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#39f"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Behind the Scenes") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Notebook") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("PORN") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("P0rn") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Porn") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Laptop") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Halo") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Minecraft") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Box Office") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Painting") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("iOS") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("iveaway") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Selena Gomez") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Justin Bieber") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("hilton") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Miley") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("ollywood") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("elfie") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Vine") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Celeb") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("elebrit") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("ntertainment") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("ascar") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("ootball") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("lympics") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("aseball") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("ennis") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("asketball") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Bikini") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Keiser") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Makeup") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );

$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Prank") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#262"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Hands On") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#262"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Redesign") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#262"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("iscover") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#262"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Solar") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#262"} )

$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Part 1") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#383"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Part 2") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#383"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Part 3") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#383"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Fails") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#383"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Bloopers") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#383"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Everything Wrong") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#383"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Mysteries") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#383"} )


$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("cience") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#393"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("cientis") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#393"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("echnology") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#393"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("uture") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#393"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("enetic") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#393"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Gameplay") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#393"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Top 5") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#393"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Top 10") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#393"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Metasploit") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#393"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Worlds") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#393"} )

$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Podcast") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#c4c"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Review") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#3c3"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Facts") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#3c3"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("CES") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#3c3"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Kickstarter") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#3c3"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("News") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#3c3"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Trailer") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#3c3"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Lets Play") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#c4c"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Episode") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#3c3"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Money") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#3c3"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Things to do") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#c4c"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("The Patch") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#c4c"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Big Think") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#c4c"} )


$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("anger") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#622"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Soaring") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#622"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("resident") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#622"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("entagon") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#622"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("nonymous") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#622"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("utonomous") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#622"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Bully") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#622"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Criminal") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#622"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("rutality") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#622"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Alien") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#622"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("axes") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#622"} )

$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Anti") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Office") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("ancer") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Cops") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Strike") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("overnment") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("adiation") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("adioactive") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("mendment") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("onfiscation") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Nuclear") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("llegal") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("eapons") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"})
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("rotest") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Prices Rising") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Verdict") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("FDA") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("FBI") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("NSA") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("CIA") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("police") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Obama") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Spy") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Suicide") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Piers Morgan") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("illionair") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Destabilize") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Dumbing Us") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Agenda") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("lying") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Afraid") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Globalist") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("assword") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("inflation") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#822"} )

$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("mergency") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("ombing") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("ijack") ')  .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("llness") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Deaths") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Death") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Caught") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Witness") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Leak") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("ncovered") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("hemical") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Crash") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("reatens") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Riot") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("oisened") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Hack") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Credit") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("usion Centers") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("rivate Sector") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Virus") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Terroist") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("DEAD") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Kills") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Killed") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Murder") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
$( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Mobs") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22"} )
  $( '.yt-lockup-title a:contains("Martial") ') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#a22" , "display":"block"} )

}, 10000);

jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ok this is possible. for firefox-addon-sdk you use `contentScriptFile` like this:

```
var self = require('sdk/self');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.open({
    url: self.data.url('ui/popup.html'),
    onOpen: function (tab) {
        var tabWorker = tab.attach({
            contentScriptFile: [
                self.data.url('ui/libs/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'),
                self.data.url('any-additonal-js-file-you-want-to-import.js')
            ]
        });
        tabWorker.port.emit('set-active-tab', tab.id);
    }
});
```

for bootstrap addon this example does what you need:
https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9406437